# Can MVC (2) views reference an assembly in the GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference, .net-assembly

I have an MVC2 view that uses a property of a type defined in a class library assembly.

E.G.

```
<div><%= Model.MyClass.MyProperty %></div>
```

If I have my class library assembly referenced with Copy Local = false (so it is not copied to the bin), I get an exception when the view loads saying "MyProperty was not found on type MyClass, am I missing a reference?". With Copy Local = true for the assembly, the view loads correctly.

The server I'm deploying this MVC site on already has the class library assembly in the GAC. The MVC site finds it and uses it in various controller actions prior to my requesting this view, but when the view tries to use it directly inline, it blows up with the error above. I don't want to have to maintain two copies of the same assembly. Is there any way to make the view find the GAC assembly that's clearly already loaded and in use?

Comment: Can you post exact error instead of typing it in? There is chance that your view uses wrong version of assembly too...

Answer (score 2):

Views have there own `using` section in the `web.config`.  This specific `web.config` lives in the root of the Views folder, Not the application root.  Here is an example (there may be slight difference as this is a MVC 5 config):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

You most likely need to add the namespace that contains the class you are using in this file.

#### Update 1

You may also need to register the assembly in the root web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0" >
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Company.Web.Whatever, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=521aae76165ca3e4" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

What you need to keep in mind is that such a reference requires the **fully qualified assembly name** in order to work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the Views had their own web.config. But when I add the namespace and the assembly's in the GAC, not the bin, I get the same error: "The type or namespace name '[My Root Namespace]' could not be found" except it's complaining about the new entry in the web.config and not the view now.

Comment: You may need to update the web.config (update 1).  Other than that you may want to make sure the assembly is correctly registered in the GAC (.net 4.0+ requires gacutil).  Also, I think it is worth mentioning, that [future version of .Net will not be relying on the GAC](http://www.asp.net/vnext), so you may want to adjust your framework/architecture.